# Is it bad practice to store/translate static error strings in a form field model?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, architecture, localization

I'm building a Flutter app where I have a sign-up form that will throw an error if the user inputs an invalid email.

I have the following model for the email form field (using [formz](https://pub.dev/packages/formz) package):

```dart
enum EmailFieldValidationError { empty, invalid }

class EmailField extends FormzInput<String, EmailFieldValidationError> {
  const EmailField.pure() : super.pure('');

  const EmailField.dirty([String value = '']) : super.dirty(value);

  static final RegExp _emailRegExp = RegExp(
    r'^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$',
  );

  @override
  EmailFieldValidationError? validator(String? value) {
  }

  String? get errorText {
    if (error != null && !pure && value.isNotEmpty) {
      switch (error) {
        case EmailFieldValidationError.invalid:
          return 'Invalid email.';
        default:
          return null;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

This makes things very simple for now within my widgets when I want to conditionally show error messages under a `TextFormField()`, but this seems to me like bad practice when considering how localization (which I would like to add to the app later) in flutter would require me to use the `BuildContext` to *build* the error strings instead. Like so:

```dart
  String? buildErrorText(BuildContext context) {
    if (error != null && !pure && value.isNotEmpty) {
      switch (error) {
        case EmailFieldValidationError.invalid:
          return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.emailFieldInvalidValueError;
        default:
          return null;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Given that I'd need to instantiate a `BuildContext` and configure it with my localization class just to be able to test this form field model, I think that there is poor separation of concerns here.

I thought it would be a good idea at first to generate error texts for my form field models within the class itself. This was primarily to avoid repeated code. But after localization became a nice-to-have for my app, this became a problem, and I'm running into analysis paralysis reading/considering different options for spearating the static string generation from the model class while avoiding my original problem of repeated code.

Any ideas would be much appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a simple solution eventually and since I didn't get any viable answers, here is my solution. It would be nice if anyone could validate or give feedback to further improve it.

I basically created a new "common" widget to simply render a `TextFormField` based on the given `EmailField` value. If the current value has any errors, it will render an appropriate error string based on the error type:

```dart
class CommonEmailFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  const CommonEmailFormField({
    Key? key,
    required this.email,
    this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final EmailField email;
  final Function(String)? onChanged;

  String? get _errorText {
    if (email.error != null && !email.pure && email.value.isNotEmpty) {
      switch (email.error) {
        case EmailFieldValidationError.invalid:
          return 'Invalid email.';
        default:
          return null;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      initialValue: email.value,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Email *',
        errorText: _errorText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've simplified the snippet to be concise and to the point. You can take a look at the actual implementation [here](https://github.com/HRahimy/positive_affirmations/blob/master/src/app_rework/lib/common/widgets/form_fields/common_email_form_field.dart).

Once I start adding localization, it will require me to change the `_errorText` getter read the static localized strings from the `BuildContext`, but that's still code that drives UI behavior and I maintain separation of concerns.

Regardless, this solution solves my main problems of:

1. Unnecessary complexity in testing. Now I don't need to set up a UI `BuildContext` to be able to test field models once I add localization.
2. Repeated code. I can just reuse this common widget wherever else I need.
3. Separation of concerns. Code that drives specifically UI/View behavior is nicely separated from code that drives Model behavior. This in-turn simplifies testing.